# Range Hood Ventilation - Working around a stud

Tags: ventilation, range

I need to install a simple under the cabinet range hood with ventilation to the outside.  Of course, there is a stud blocking the easy horizontal path to the adjacent exterior wall.  I suppose I could go straight up out the roof.  But I am not doing that myself.  My questions are:

1. Is there such thing as a standard adapters suited to solve this problem?  The stud is offset about 2" from where the center of the centered vent would be if there were no stud.
2. Is there such thing as a range hood designed with this scenario in mind?  i.e. one with an offset vent.

Surprisingly haven't been able to find answers to those questions googling.  Only suggestion I've seen is to make a detailed drawing of what you want and take it to a sheet metal shop.  I don't trust myself to generate a good enough drawing.

Other option is to move the stud.  I think I know how to do that, but it would be nice if that mess could be avoided.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If the answer serves you well, you can click the question mark next to it to mark it as "accepted." And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many range hoods have options to route out the back (no good for you) or out the top. Vent out the top, use a right angle to go left or right and then another right angle to go back through the wall between studs.

Comment: Slight change... use an adjustable elbow or 45 deg to go up & to the side, another if needed to go more sideways & through the wall, then put a cabinet or decorative box over it to hide the ductwork. Another option... if yours has a rectangular vent out the top instead of round you can get an offset rectangular to round adapter from an hvac supplier, then go from there.